# В каких случаях применяется DUAL и какой смысл этом?

Tags: oracle

Вопрос теоретический. Изучаю Oracle и встречаю такую конструкцию как DUAL. Понимаю, что  это некоторая виртуальная таблица, но мне бы хотелось понять сам смысл этой штуки, зачем и когда применяется.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

В синтаксически корректном запросе ОБЯЗАНА быть секция FROM.

Иногда требуется запрос/подзапрос, выполняющий формирование литералов (либо выполняющий константные вычисления), т.е. не основывающийся на какой-либо таблице. Например, CTE, генерирующая набор чисел или список дат. Однако секция FROM в запросе быть обязана - именно в этом случае и используется `FROM DUAL`. Т.е. и синтаксис соблюдён, и явно сказано, что таблицы для выполнения запроса не нужны. Подробности см. ниже.

---

Например, в запросе требуется набор чисел от 1 до 9. Задача решается простейшим CTE.

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 1 num FROM DUAL
              UNION ALL
              SELECT num+1 FROM cte WHERE num < 9 )
```

Базовая часть UNION-запроса возвращает литерал - единицу, от которой потом и пляшет рекурсивная часть. Источника данных (таблицы) в этой части UNION-запроса никакой нет и в помине. Однако FROM обязан быть. И на помощь приходит `FROM DUAL`.

Аналогично будет, если в запросе нужен список кастомных литеральных значений. Например

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN ( SELECT 2000 "year" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 2005        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 2008        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 2013        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
       SELECT 2014        FROM DUAL           ) "years"
...
```

Или если нужно выполнить какие-то вычисления с константами

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN ( SELECT 1024 bytes_to_kbytes, 
              1024*1024 bytes_to_Mbytes 
              1024*1024*1024 bytes_to_Gbytes 
       FROM DUAL ) koefficients
...
```

или переменными

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN ( SELECT ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -@delta1-@delta2) period_start, 
              ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -@delta2) period_end
       FROM DUAL ) periods
...
```

---

Если обратиться к документации ([Selecting from the DUAL Table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036)), то:

> DUAL is a table automatically created by Oracle Database along with the data dictionary. DUAL is in the schema of the user SYS but is accessible by the name DUAL to all users. It has one column, DUMMY, defined to be VARCHAR2(1), and contains one row with a value X. Selecting from the DUAL table is useful for computing a constant expression with the SELECT statement. Because DUAL has only one row, the constant is returned only once. Alternatively, you can select a constant, pseudocolumn, or expression from any table, but the value will be returned as many times as there are rows in the table. Refer to ["About SQL Functions"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions001.htm#CJAHCIID) for many examples of selecting a constant value from DUAL.

Если коротко, то `DUAL` - это физически реальная таблица, которая находится в схеме пользователя `sys`, но доступна на чтение любому пользователю. Она имеет единственное поле с именем `DUMMY` типа `VARCHAR2(1)` и единственную запись со значением `'X'` в этом поле. Что собственно гарантирует, что при её использовании в качестве источника данных будет получена только одна итоговая запись. Если не выполнять обращение именно к полю `DUMMY`, то при использовании `FROM DUAL` физического доступа к таблице не происходит (`FAST DUAL`, верно для **Oracle Database 10g Release 1** и старше).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а практический какой-то маленький пример можно увидеть?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Пжалста.

Comment: Спасибо, круто.

Comment: Получается мы можем встроить в запрос простой набор данных нужный нам именно сейчас без физически присутствующей таблицы.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Угу.

Comment: Разве будет работать без WITH cte (num) ... ?

Comment: @hinotf А чё ему не работать-то? добавил примеры. Синтетические, конечно, но жизнь-то богаче фантазии...

Comment: "_что таблицы для выполнения запроса не нужны_" - но dual то и есть таблица с одной колонкой и одной строкой в схеме sys. Может как-то переформулировать потому, что ТС считает, что это виртуальная таблица. Но dual это физическая таблица без данных и служит как заменитель когда таблица с данными не нужна.

Comment: @0xdb Добавил...

Comment: Очень интересно и за примеры спасибо

Comment: Ну раз ТС интересно, то порядок +